# writing an sql query to display specific charges

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing an sql query to display names of guests who have incurred both athletic and dinner charges on their itinerary. Can someone point me in the right direction as to setting up the query?

this is what i have but gives no result..

```
SELECT GUEST.FIRSTNAME, CHARGETYPE.DESCRIPTION
FROM GUEST, CHARGES, CHARGETYPE
WHERE CHARGETYPE.CHARGEID = CHARGES.CHARGEID
AND CHARGES.CHARGEID = '07'
AND CHARGES.CHARGEID = '03'
```

the chargeid 07 and 03 reflect athletic and dinner charges respectfully. im sorry for the lack of info, first time really using stackoverflow.

Here is the CHARGETYPE table

```
CHARGEID and DESCRIPTION are the column names
01  ROOM DEPOSIT        
02  LUNCH SERVICE       
03  DINNER SERVICE      
04  BREAKFAST SERVICE   
05  ROOM CHARGE         
06  GIFTSHOP PURCHASE   
07  ATHLETIC CHARGE         

CHARGEID, ITINID, CHARGETIME, AMOUNT, GUESTID are the columns for the CHARGES table
01  001 11:00   -1850001
02  001 14:00   30  0001
03  001 18:00   55  0001
04  001 11:00   20  0001
05  001 20:00   20  0001
08  001 12:00   20  0001
01  002 16:00   -185    0002
02  002 16:30   40  0002
04  002 10:00   20  0002
05  002 14:00   25  0002
09  002 15:00   25  0002
01  003 10:00   -185    0003
02  003 12:00   30  0003
03  003 18:00   50  0003
04  003 11:00   18  0003
05  003 12:30   27  0003
06  003 14:45   30  0003
01  004 11:00   -185    0004
02  004 13:00   40  0004
03  004 19:00   60  0004
04  004 11:00   15  0004
05  004 20:00   34  0004
01  005 10:00   -185    0005
02  005 12:00   30  0005
03  005 17:00   30  0005
04  005 10:00   10  0005
05  005 16:00   25  0005
01  006 11:00   -185    0001
02  006 12:00   22  0001
03  006 18:00   40  0001
04  006 08:00   15  0001
05  006 20:00   60  0001
07  006 14:00   50  0001
01  007 11:00   -185    0003
02  007 12:00   20  0003
03  007 17:00   55  0003
04  007 10:00   15  0003
05  007 16:00   45  0003
01  008 11:00   -185    0005
02  008 13:00   20  0005
03  008 18:00   60  0005
04  008 09:00   20  0005
05  008 22:00   65  0005
07  008 12:00   50  0005
```

.

```
GUESTID LASTNAME FIRSTNAME are the columns for the GUEST table
0001    SMITH       JOHN         
0002    SMITH       LISA        
0003    ADAMS       PETER       
0004    ADAMS       JANE        
0005    JOHNSON     DEAN
```

Comment: Edit your question and add table structure, sample data, and what you've tried.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has shown no effort at solving the problem on his own.

Comment: I edited my question to show the code I currently have. please dont vote this "off-topic"

Comment: You are joining `GUEST` to `CHARGES` but you don't define how they are joined. Once you define your join then change that `WHERE` to be an `OR` not an `AND` you'll probably maybe have what you need.

Comment: we do not know what your table schema looks like, this makes it very hard to provide a working solution to your question.  Please re-read @EatPeanutButter 's comment and provided the detail requested.

Comment: Hopefully this is enough information needed to shed some light on my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT G.FIRSTNAME,G.LASTNAME, CT.DESCRIPTION
  FROM GUEST G
 INNER JOIN  CHARGETYPE CT
    ON G.GUESTID = C.GUESTID
 INNER JOIN CHARGES 
    ON  CT.CHARGEID = C.CHARGEID
 WHERE C.CHARGEID IN ('07','03' );
```

Comment: CHARGEID can't both be '07' AND '03' at the same time.  Consider an IN list for these values.

Comment: when i tried your solution it said that "C.GUESTID" is an invalid identifier

Comment: You should post ur sample input and output along with table structures. I just  wrote the query based on what u provided.

Comment: I edited my original question and added all relevant tables along with the column names, etc.